# with taking the sum of a list but changing the odd elements to be negative

Tags: python

Write a function alternating_sign_sum(nums) that takes a possibly-empty list of numbers nums as a parameter and returns the result

nums[0] - nums[1] + nums[2] - nums[3] ...
i.e. the sums of all the numbers but with all the odd-numbered elements negated. If the list is empty, the return value should be zero. Your function should not modify the list passed as a parameter.

```
def alternating_sign_sum(nums):
    """yo"""    
    lis = 0
    for num in nums:
        if num & 1 == 1:
            num = num * -1
        if num % 2 == 0:
            num = num * 1
        
        lis += num
    return (lis)
```

Comment: So, what's the problem that you're facing?

Answer (score 2):

A simple element-by-element approach similar to yours would use a multiplier that alternated between one and negative one, along the lines of:

```py
    def alternating_sign_sum(the_list):
        the_sum = 0
        the_mult = 1
        for item in the_list:
            the_sum = the_sum + the_mult * item
            the_mult = -the_mult
        return the_sum
```

However, the *Pythonic* way would just be to use two list comprehensions to do it, one handling the odd element indexes, the other handling the even ones:

```py
    def alternating_sign_sum(the_list):
        return sum(the_list[0::2]) - sum(the_list[1::2])
```

This works because the list slice `0::2` means start at element zero (the first element), consume all elements, but only every second one. So that's the first, third, fifth, and so on. Similarly, `1::2` means the second, fourth and so on.

A version of that final one with test harness is below:

```py
def alternating_sign_sum(the_list):
    return sum(the_list[0::2]) - sum(the_list[1::2])

print(alternating_sign_sum([]))
print(alternating_sign_sum([7]))
print(alternating_sign_sum([7, 2]))
print(alternating_sign_sum([1, 2, 3, 4]))
```

and produces, as expected:

```sh
0
7
5
-2
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use `enumerate` then you can get the index and value from the list

```
result = sum([(1 if ind%2 == 0 else -1)*val for ind, val in enumerate(nums)])
```

Answer (score -1):

You can iterate through the list and add the even positions and subtract the odd position values:

```
def alternating_sign_sum(nums):
    total = 0
    for i, v in enumerate(nums):
        if i%2 == 1:
            total += (v*-1)
        else:
            total += v
    return total

print(alternating_sign_sum([1, 2, 3, 4]))
```

**Output:**

```
-2
```

**Alternate solution using list comprehension:**

```
def alternating_sign_sum(nums):
    return sum([v if i%2 == 0 else v*-1 for i, v in enumerate(nums)])

print(alternating_sign_sum([1, 2, 3, 4]))
```